# React Native Delete Function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, logic

The intended function is that it would just delete the one goal that is clicked but for some odd reason it decides onPress to delete all goals listed.

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSRrxpdMpVc and im stuck around 2:44:45. If anyone else has done this tutorial and or can see my problem an explanation would be greatly appreciated. :)

Program

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList
} from "react-native";

import GoalItem from "./components/GoalItem";
import GoalInput from "./components/GoalInput";

export default function App() {
  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]);

  const addGoalHandler = goalTitle => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [
      ...currentGoals,
      { key: Math.random().toString(), value: goalTitle }
    ]);
  };

  const removeGoalHander = goalId => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => {
      return currentGoals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId);
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <GoalInput onAddGoal={addGoalHandler} />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        data={courseGoals}
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <GoalItem
            id={itemData.item.id}
            onDelete={removeGoalHander}
            title={itemData.item.value}
          />
        )}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: 80
  }
});
```

Function

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const GoalItem = props => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onDelete.bind(this, props.id)}>
      <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderColor: "grey",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 10
  }
});

export default GoalItem;
```

Comment: I figured it out it was the line ```{ key: Math.random().toString(), value: goalTitle }``` that needs to be changed to ```{ id: Math.random().toString(), value: goalTitle }```

Answer (score 0):

When updating state, you have to pass new array so component can detect changes and update view

```
const removeGoalHander = goalId => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => {
      const newGoals = currentGoals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId);
      return [...newGoals];
    });
  };
```